# expected identifier char JOPtion

Tags: java, char

```
        m = input.length();

        char[]sort = new.char [m];
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Selecet [A/D]:");
        for (s = 0; 3<m; s++)
        {
            if(sort[a] = input.charAt(a));
        }
        if (input.charAt(0) == 'A' || input.charAt(0) == 'a');
        {
```

I keep getting error on the line:

```
>char[]sort = new.char [m];
```

... saying that "line identifier expected".

Can you please help, I cant seem to get it running.

Comment: Instead of completely modifying the question with a new one, you should have accepted @moffeltje's answer and made a new question..

Answer (score 6):

Change

```
char[]sort = new.char [m];
```

to

```
char[]sort = new char [m];
```

[`new`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html) is a keyword, not an object/class. Every time you use [`new`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html) (as a keyword) a new object or array will be created.

**Update**
Since you just **totally changed** the question, here is the answer to your new question (although I think you should rollback to your original question and ask another):

You didn't initialize `input`, so it has no value. That is why you cannot compare it using `input.equals(password)`.

You have to retrieve the input from the user or at least, initialize the input to:

```
String input = "";
```

and you may want to have this:

```
//...code
JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Enter the Password:");
input = IN.readLine();
if(input.equals(password)){
//...code
```

Comment: for (s = 0; 3<m; s++)
    {
     if(sort[a] = input.charAt(a));
    }   how about this one i keep getting the error incompatible types and it points to the '=' sign

Comment: @RedondoVelasco Well I'm not sure what you want to achieve with that piece of code but there seems a lot wrong or not logical. Why the if statement with no body? And what is the variable `a`? (it does not change during the loop) And why is `s` unused?

Comment: @RedondoVelasco depending on the value of m, and whether it changes, I think that will be an infinite loop (given your current code, seems infinite to me).